# Can't remove Libre office Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-uninstall

I have Libre office installed on Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to remove it but even though it say's it is uninstalled it still works, exists, and most importantly of all takes up my disk space. I have tried to uninstall it by command line but it says "not installed so not removing" and it does not appear in the Ubuntu software center so I cant remove it there either. I also tried uninstalling it by clicking the menu option in dash but that does not do anything either. I was wondering if any one knows how to remove Libre office? if at all possible that is.

this is the resault to guru's command:

```
Package 'libreoffice-ogltrans' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-pdfimport' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-presentation-minimizer' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-sdbc-firebird' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-style-human' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-style-tango' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-writer' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'browser-plugin-libreoffice' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-emailmerge' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-gtk3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-kde' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-librelogo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-mysql-connector' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-presenter-console' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-report-builder' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-report-builder-bin' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-script-provider-bsh' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-script-provider-js' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-script-provider-python' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-style-crystal' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-style-galaxy' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-style-hicontrast' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-style-oxygen' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-style-sifr' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-subsequentcheckbase' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-wiki-publisher' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-opensymbol libboost-date-time1.54.0 libclucene-contribs1
  libclucene-core1 libcmis-0.4-4 libcolamd2.8.0 libexttextcat-2.0-0
  libexttextcat-data libhyphen0 liblangtag-common liblangtag1 libmhash2
  libmythes-1.2-0 libneon27-gnutls libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libyajl2
  lp-solve uno-libs3 ure xfonts-mathml
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I had to trim some as the post was to large besides it was just a bunch of is not installed, so not removed anyway.

Update

I don't know exactly what just happened but I tried to open Libre office again and I got a black screen with white writing that printed out a bunch of numbers and at the bottom it said "kernel panic - fatal exception" and I had to restart manually but after that Libre office seems to be gone so that's good I guess.

Comment: Its certainly possible, but libreoffice is composed of multiple packages. Which one did you remove.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*`. It will remove Libre Office completely with all packages from your system.

Comment: I tried all of these: libreoffice-writter libreoffice-calc libreoffice-impress libreoffice-draw libreoffice-base libreoffice-math

Comment: Did you install it by compiling source?

Comment: I just got a huge number of "not installed so not removing" and it's still there and it still works.

Comment: No I did not install it at all. it was pre-installed along with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Did you read @Guru's [comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/515188/cant-remove-libre-office-ubuntu-14-04#comment698033_515188)? this is actually your answer. Copy (sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*) in terminal and hit enter then press `y` and enter again.

Comment: Yes I did read Guru's comment and all that it did was give me a whole bunch of not installed so not removing. The Libre office is still there and working as far as I can tell.

Comment: Post your error output after running suggested command. also with your tried code, please

Comment: I don't know exactly what just happened but I tried to open Libre office again and I got a black screen with white writing that printed out a bunch of numbers and at the bottom it said "kernel panic - fatal exception" and I had to restart manually but after that Libre office seems to be gone so that's good I guess. @KasiyA Sorry I was not able to log what ever that was as I had to restart the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As @muru pointed out ncdu command is not present by default so you have to install it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install ncdu
```

Run the following commands on your terminal

```
cd /
ncdu -x -q
```

Navigate to the directories where these packages are present and remove them manually. But be careful because you don't want to remove anything other than libre-office packages.

Comment: -1: a) `ncdu` isn't installed by default. b) the `locate` command would be better.

Comment: @muru Edited to reflect ncdu installation. IMHO, ncdu would be better because it is really easy to navigate using ncdu interface. I wanted to remove MATLAB and after trying to search for individual directories, I couldn't find main installation. I installed ncdu and it took me just a minute to solve the problem.

Comment: If all you want to do is find a location, `locate` is still the best, and fastest tool. Try it out someday. Removing the downvote for now.

Comment: I used your method to find the last couple fragments of the file so i'm giving you the best answer but I do agree with muru that locate is better as you don't have to install anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-common
```

seems to work for me.